How do I include a cell value as the context when using the Excel LARGE function without macros/VBS?
I'm not sure how to phrase the question. I have a matrix of data that lists applications on the rows and teams that requested them on the columns. An X is used to mark the intersection for a team and application. I use the =COUNTIF function to tally how many teams have requested an app. e.g.



App
Team1
Team2
Count




App1
X

1


App2
X
X
2


App3
X
X
2



To the side of this data I use the =LARGE function to list the x largest values of the Count column, e.g.:



Top 3 Requested Apps




2


2


1



This isn't entirely useful for our needs, though. Those values need to be easily correlated to the apps. How do I refer to the cell with the app name so I can have



App
Request Count




App2
2


App3
2


App1
1



Our security posture prevents the use of unsigned macros or VBS scripts so I'd like to avoid those unless this can't be done without one them.

Use TAKE and SORT
=TAKE(SORT(CHOOSECOLS(A2:D4,1,4),2,-1),,x)

Where x is the number of rows you want.


Thank you for the solution. I did have to make one minor alteration: you list x in the columns position. I moved it to the rows position when I inserted it into my sheet; e.g. ...),x,)
